# Surveillance camera is pointed at the street

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, recording

My neighbours have complained to me that the surveillance camera installed at the front of my house is also capturing areas outside my land title as defined in the registry. I haven't checked that but it is capturing some of the street in the background as installed to point at the gate to our house.

Is it illegal to position surveillance cameras in a way that public areas are partially captured or captured in the background?

Comment: The answer to the question is, "No," but I'm more inclined to close this as another [IXL](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/414/dealing-with-is-x-illegal-questions) question.

Answer (score 2):

In common law countries, unless there is a statute to the contrary you do not have the right not to be photographed. That is how paparazzi make their living and while many people think that it's odious a) it's not illegal and b) a lot of those people must be buying the magazines.

Provided the camera has the permission of the property owner then anything it can see is fair game.